# Is using jquery makes the webpage to take long time when loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know that which method is good using native javascript or jquery to build a high quality site.Does jquery make the page load time longer?

Comment: Not if you do it right. In fact jQuery will in many ways make the page load quicker, as jQuery itself is very often cached on the user's machine.

Comment: is jquery code shorter than javascript

Comment: No, because jQuery is JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, given that jQuery is just a bunch of JavaScript designed to make the coder's life easier while totally ignoring the basic fundamentals of "less is more", "KISS" and other similar principles, I'd say raw JavaScript is a *hell* of a lot faster than jQuery in terms of page loading times.

That said, it is of course entirely possible to write plain JavaScript that kills the browser.
Such as `while(some condition that is accidentally always true)` (I am guilty of this one)

So just "not using jQuery" won't guarantee that your site works faster than one that uses jQuery. You still need to optimise the code you write, regardless of the tools you use.